# How to remove column from dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable and having trash icon at the "th". I need to remove entire column when click on the trash icon(need to remove all data from all pages). I tried the following code but which is not working under pagination.Please help me...

```
$(document).on("click", ".a_datatbl_trash", function (e)
{
   var indexToRemove = $(this).parent().index();
   $("#datatable-buttons tbody tr").each(function() {
      $(this).find("td:eq("+indexToRemove+")").remove();
   });
   $(this).closest("th").remove();
)};
```

This is the html structure

```
<thead>
<tr role="row">
  <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Article title: activate to sort column descending">Article title
  <a href="" class="dragtable-drag-handle" style="background: none; width: 15px;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows"></i></a>
  <a href="" class="a_datatbl_trash" style="float: right;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash datatbl_trash" style="float: right;"></i></a>
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the visible API? Does it not fit your need?
that could be something like:

```
yourDatatable.column(columnIndex).visible(false);
```

Or you go to destroy the data first and update.

Comment: I am glad it helps :)